# Подсчет букв, символов и строк

Tags: java

Программа должна подсчитывать кол-во букв, символов и строк. Для выхода из цикла есть оператор if, который при вводе пустой строки автоматически завершает его. И теперь столкнулся с проблемой чтения текстов, у которых предложения могут быть разделены пустой строкой. Как можно модернизировать код, чтобы при первой же пустой строки он не выходил из цикла?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problema006 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String in = null;
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int counter3 = 0;
    while ((in = scan.nextLine()) != null || scan.hasNextLine() ){


        if(in.equals(""))
                break;

        char[] tmp = in.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(tmp[i])) {
                counter1++;
            }
            else if(Character.isLetter(tmp[i])){
                counter2++;
            }
        }
        counter3++;

    }
    System.out.printf("%3d letters\n%3d digits\n%3d lines \n", counter2, counter1, counter3);
    scan.close();
}
}
```

И для примера есть текст:

> Capítulo 1
>
> En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha
>   mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los lanza en astillero, adarga
>   antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor.
>
> Capítulo 2
>
> Hechas, pues, estas prevenciones, no quiso aguardar más tiempo a poner
>   en efeto su pensamiento, apretándole a ello la falta que él pensaba
>   que hacía al mundo su tardanza, según eran los agravios que pensaba
>   deshacer, tuertos que enderezar, sinrazones que enmendar y abusos que
>   mejorar y deudas que satisfacer.

И выход:
406 letters
2 digits
11 lines

Comment: выходите, если введено две пустые строки подряд. Это стандартная практика

Comment: Как тогда можно сделать, чтобы считывался текст с пустой строкой и при повторной пустой строке завершался цикл?

Comment: Сохраняйте пердпоследний ввод в отдельной переменной и сравнивайте две строки

Answer (score 2):

Ничего вам не надо добавлять. Сканер и сам отлично поймет, когда документ закончился. Слишком много лишних условий, которые Вам же и мешают. Пробуйте написать свой метод так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "1.txt";
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
        int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0, counter3 = 0;
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            for (char ch : scan.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
                if (Character.isDigit(ch)) counter1++;
                else if (Character.isLetter(ch)) counter2++;
            }
            counter3++;
        }
        System.out.printf("%3d letters\n%3d digits\n%3d lines \n", counter2, counter1, counter3);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){System.out.println("File Not Found: " + e);}
}
```

Переменная fileName - путь к вашему файлу + его имя. путь может быть как абсолютный , так и относительный. У меня в примере это текстовый файл 1.txt, который лежит в корне проекта.
Единственное, что в данном случае будут считаться и пустые строки, если хотите этого избежать, то перед третим счетчиком пишите условный оператор с проверкой на пустую строку и всех делов.